# Autofac configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am just starting with Autofac and I am trying to configure a simple registration, according to the docs this should work:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<CurrentUserInfo>().As<ICurrentUserInfo>();
```

But I am getting:

Incorrect Number of type parameters

And according to the docs:

```
 _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
```

But there is no Build Method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarted Visual Studio..corrupted cache or something

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have referenced both `Autofac.dll` and `Autofac.Configuration.dll`.

Comment: I just inpected the ContainerBuilder class using reflector and there is a public Build method....

Comment: Restarted Visual Studio..corrupted cache or something